# Want to delete columns based on strings in a sheet

Tags: excel, vba

Made up this code but can't get to the part to loop through the sheets with the defined headers to delete thanks guys.

```
Sub deleteCol()

On Error Resume Next
Dim Coldellr As Long
Dim colval As String
Dim wbCurrent As Workbook
Dim wsCurrent As Worksheet
Dim nLastCol, i As Integer
Dim LngLp As Long

Coldellr = Sheets("Coldel").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row 'Define LastRow

Set wbCurrent = ActiveWorkbook
Set wsCurrent = wbCurrent.ActiveSheet
'This next variable will get the column number of the very last column that has data in it, so we can use it in a loop later
nLastCol = wsCurrent.Cells.Find("*", LookIn:=xlValues, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column

'This loop will go through each column header and delete the column if the header contains "Percent Margin of Error"
For i = nLastCol To 1 Step -1
  For LngLp = 1 To Coldellr
  Set colval = Sheets("Coldel").Range("a" & LngLp).Value

    If InStr(1, wsCurrent.Cells(1, i).Value, colval, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        wsCurrent.Columns(i).Delete Shift:=xlShiftToLeft
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: so your code works correctly for `wsCurrent` and you only need to make it loop through all `wbCurrent` sheets?

Answer (score 0):

used your code to add in a loop for each sheet. Should work.

```
Sub deleteCol()

    On Error Resume Next
    Dim Coldellr As Long
    Dim colval As String
    Dim wbCurrent As Workbook
    Dim wsCurrent As Worksheet
    Dim nLastCol, i As Integer
    Dim LngLp As Long

    Coldellr = Sheets("Coldel").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'Define LastRow

    Set wbCurrent = ActiveWorkbook

    Dim sh As Worksheet  '@nightcrawler23

    For Each sh In wbCurrent.Sheets '@nightcrawler23

        Set wsCurrent = sh  '@nightcrawler23

        'This next variable will get the column number of the very last column that has data in it, so we can use it in a loop later
        nLastCol = wsCurrent.Cells.Find("*", LookIn:=xlValues, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column

        'This loop will go through each column header and delete the column if the header contains "Percent Margin of Error"
        For i = nLastCol To 1 Step -1
          For LngLp = 1 To Coldellr

            ' Edit:
            ' removed Set here as a value is being assigned
            colval = Sheets("Coldel").Range("a" & LngLp).Value

            If InStr(1, wsCurrent.Cells(1, i).Value, colval, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                wsCurrent.Columns(i).Delete Shift:=xlShiftToLeft
            End If
        Next i

    Next sh '@nightcrawler23



End Sub
```

Comment: hmmm I still get a compile error object required at this line which is what I had before

Set colval = Sheets("Coldel").Range("a" & LngLp).Value

Comment: See revised code. Since you are assigning the value of the cell to a variable, you do not need a `Set`. `Set colval = Sheets("Coldel").Range("a" & LngLp)` would have been correct also. In your question you never mentioned that an error was occuring at that line. Please amke sure to clearly state your problems in fututre